# Ruby: start thin: No adapter found for /home/ubuntu

Tags: ruby, thin

I tried to install Image Magically on Ubuntu which is on an Amazon instance.

I followed the reference at https://github.com/afeld/magickly for that.

There I followed the following steps to install Image Magically on server.

```
$ gem install magickly
```

After that I installed the “thin” gem using under given command.

```
$ gem install thin
```

Then I tried to start `thin` gem with following command.

```
$ thin start
```

But it gives me the error: `No adapter found for /home/ubuntu`

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

You have to create the application, here is how:

Create an application directory:

```
mkdir magickly
cd magickly
```

Create `Gemfile` file with following content:

```
gem 'magickly'
```

Create `config.ru` file with following content:

```
require 'magickly'
run Magickly::App
```

Run `bundle install`.
Now you can start the server:

```
thin start
```

and access the app at `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Thanks mechanicalfish,

            Your answer really helped me and my magically app has started. But I can’t access this app at http://localhost:3000.  

When I start “thin” using command “thin start”, it gets started in terminal and shows message

“Using rack adapter
Thin web server (v1.6.1 codename Death Proof)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop”


So according to message, I tried to access app at http://0.0.0.0:3000, but can’t access it.

What changes should I do if I want to access this app on Amazon Instance Domain?

Comment: As I have installed this app on Amazon Instance.

Comment: If you installed this on an Amazon Instance, then you cannot access it via 0.0.0.0:3000. You need to type in your instance's *public* IP and :3000. And of course your instance's security settings should allow connections to port 3000 from outside.

Answer (score 0):

For others who get the error: `thin: No adapter found for /home/ubuntu` :
You might simply have forgotten to `cd` to the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error message because the service user Thin was configured to use isn't permitted to `cd` to the directory. The `cd` silently failed and it then complained not to find the adapter which is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Before using `thin start` you have to execute `thin install`